# Get the transform matrix between identical 3D objects

Tags: matrices, 3d

The problem: I have two instances of the same object in a space coordinate system. I want to know the transform Matrix between those objects (translation and rotation).
I have access to all the vertices, points, edges or faces.

At first, I wanted to use the Iterative Closest Point algorithm (ICP) but as my element are the same, I thought this was too much.

Do you know a simpler version of the ICP for this specific case or another way to get the transform matrix?

PS: I'm more used to programming than mathematics so I'll better understand an answer in pseudocode than a formula.

Comment: Try first the barycenter, so you have the translation between then. After that. try the main inertia axes, so to have an rotation idea, etc.

Comment: If you have object A and object B which are the same up to translation and rotation, do you know which vertices in A map to which vertices in B individually or do you have to detect the orientation without knowing this?

Comment: @CyclotomicField I don't know the corresponding vertices, I can get a bag of points, vertices or faces. I could try to sort them by length but I'll have to set up another arbitrary condition in case of equality.